# FB like text-align: right instead of left

Tags: html, facebook

```
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={0}&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80
```

I am using iframe.

whole code:

```
string iframe = string.Format("<iframe src=\"http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={0}&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px; text-align:right;\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>", fullUrl);
            return iframe;
```

problem i have is that text is positionibg left instead of right

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=<?php echo('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px; background-color:#CCCCCC"; align="right"></iframe>
```

Comment: You should widen the width and height of that div or table in which you are placing this iframe

Comment: ok then do less the width and height of iframe. Then see the result

Answer (score 0):

Well ofcourse it is. You cannot specify text-align for a iframe. You have to do it within the document that is included in the iframe.

Comment: i try to add text-align outside in div but it is the same